# Prove that $\int_0^1 {\bf v \, . \, W}(s)\: {\bf v} \, ds = 0$ for skew matrix $\bf W$ and vector $\bf v$

Tags: integration, skew-symmetric-matrices

I'm at a loss as to how to show that

$\int_0^1 {\bf v \, . \, W}(s)\: {\bf v} \, ds = 0$

For any vector ${\bf v}$, where ${\bf W}(s)$ is skew (symmetric) at every point in $s$.

This assertion is from page 310 of [Continuum Mechanics by C.S. Jog](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/continuum-mechanics/8E4AE467BC749395284A5A34B3BCC25F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any skew-symmetric matrix $W$ and vector $v$, we always have $v\cdot Wv = 0$, since $v\cdot Wv = W^\top v\cdot v = -Wv\cdot v = -v\cdot Wv$. (So the integration is a red herring.)

Comment: I do like smoked herring :-).

Comment: @copper.hat I like it pickled :)

Comment: AFAICS, this seems to be true for not just $v . W v$; i.e. $a . W b = 0$  for any $a$ and $b$

Comment: No, no. That only holds for the zero matrix! Look at the proof again!

Comment: Oh yeah $a . W b = - b . W a$. Correct?

Comment: Yup. That's correct. :)